# GLIB recompiled but GIO doesn't support attribute metadata

Tags: linux, glib, gvfs

I compiled Glib for myself under Linux Mint 21.1. The new version of gio doesn't support setting attribute metadata.
If I try to do this :

```
gio set "$(xdg-user-dir PROJECTS)" "metadata::custom-icon-name" folder-system
```

with original gio, preinstalled in Linux Mint, it works. If I do the same with newly compiled I obtain this error:

```
gio: Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon-name not supported
```

Moreover, doing:

```
gio info --query-writable "$(xdg-user-dir PROJECTS)"
```

Original version returns:

```
Settable attributes:
 standard::symlink-target (bytestring)
 time::access (uint64, Keep with file when moved)
 time::access-usec (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
 time::modified (uint64, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 time::modified-usec (uint32, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::gid (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::mode (uint32, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::uid (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
Writable attribute namespaces:
 metadata (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 xattr (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 xattr-sys (string, Keep with file when moved)`
```

Mine version returns the same except for this line:

```
 metadata (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
```

that is missing.

I obtained source files with apt-get source, so they should be the original.
To compile I use:

```
meson build
cd build
ninja
```

Original and recompiled version of gio is 2.72.4

I tried also:

```
meson -DAttr=true build
```

but no success.
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
instead of using:

```
meson build
```

I had to use:

```
meson setup --prefix=/usr --buildtype=release build
```